# Warning/Error in my css file: css3 document is not a known @ directive

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, media-queries

I am getting this message in my CSS file while trying to use media queries.  Here is the code sample:

```
@document url('http://www.inserthtml.com/') 
{   
     /* CSS goes here */ 

}
```

Visual Studio 2012 underlines this in red and gives the message "css3 document is not a known @ directive". Why is this?

Comment: you are getting an "error" in your css file? what is displaying an error to you, the browser or your editor? what browser / editor do you use?
CSS does not have defined "errors", so whatever message you're getting is defined on a per-tool basis.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2012 and it is the editor that is displaying the squiggly lines.

Comment: interesting. anyway, just remember that those errors are a product of your IDE rather than the language (the language is a living standard), so if you try to use experimental features, your IDE might not have support for them yet and might detect them as an "error".

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document) docs

> Initially in CSS Conditional Rules Module Level 3, @document has been
>   postponed to the level 4.

So it is not supported in CSS3 yet. You can expect it in CSS4.

[**Codrops reference**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/document/)

> The @document at-rule is currently only supported in Firefox prefixed
>   with the -moz- prefix (@-moz-document).

Also see: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-conditional-20121213/#changes

Comment: adding to this for curiosity's sake: it is supported in firefox with the `-moz` prefix.